# How can I efficiently define a variable based on multiple user choices?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, loops, if-statement

I am writing a program for a companies website that will allow them to do quotes on the phone, a process they have been doing by hand for some time. One of the things they sell is a ridge cap for a roof. The price of this Item is defined by 4 decisions made by the user.

1. Customer Pricing level, there are 3 choices (radio buttons)
2. Condition, 2 choices (flat or sculpted, drop down box)
3. Color, there are 4 choices (drop down box)
4. Width, there are 14 choices (drop down box)

Until now I have defined this variable with a huge If...else if statement, which is over 1000 lines of code. The problem is most of the products are the same and at this rate it would take me months to finish. I will post my HTML below followed by the script. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help. (note: I only posted the code that I thought was necessary to help with my issue, assume I know the surrounding tags such as table etc.)

HTML for color selection...(each color changes the price)

```
<td><form name="form2" method="post" action="">
<label for="color"></label>
<select name="color" id="color">
 <option value="galvanized">galvanized</option>
 <option value="galvalume">galvalume</option>
 <option value="metallic copper">metallic copper</option>
 <option value="red">red</option>// there are many painted colors which is why i use "else" for this price change.
</select>
</form>
```

HTML for the trim...(selection of condition and width)

```
<td>Ridge:</td>
<td><select id="ridgeChoice" name="ridgeChoice">
<option value="Sculpted">Sculpted</option>
<option value="Flat">Flat</option>
</select>&nbsp;Qty:
<input id="ridgeTrim" type="text" value="" size="3">&nbsp; Width:<select id="ridgeWidth" name="ridgeWidth">
<option value="13">13"</option>
<option value="16">16"</option>
<option value="18">18"</option>
<option value="20">20"</option>
<option value="22">22"</option>
<option value="24">24"</option>
<option value="26">26"</option>
<option value="28">28"</option>
<option value="30">30"</option>
<option value="32">32"</option>
<option value="34">34"</option>
<option value="36">36"</option>
<option value="38">38"</option>
<option value="40">40"</option>
</select>
</td>
```

The HTML for price level is simply a radio group with three choices which also effects the price.

Javascript...

```
var ridgeChoice=document.getElementById("ridgeChoice").value;
var ridgeWidth=document.getElementById("ridgeWidth").value;

var ridgePrice;
if (ridgeChoice=="Sculpted")
{
if (retailPrice.checked)
{
    if (ridgeWidth=="13")
        {
            if(colorChoice=="galvalume")
            {
                ridgePrice=14.70;
            }
            else if (colorChoice=="metallic copper")
            {
                ridgePrice=19.55;
            }
            else if (colorChoice=="galvanized")
            {
                ridgePrice=13.35;
            }
            else
            {
                ridgePrice=16.65;
            }
        }
                   else if (ridgeWidth=="16")
        {
            if(colorChoice=="galvalume")
            {
                ridgePrice=21.30;
            }
            else if (colorChoice=="metallic copper")
            {
                ridgePrice=29.50;
            }
            else if (colorChoice=="galvanized")
            {
                ridgePrice=20.5;
            }
            else
            {
                ridgePrice=22.90;
            }
        }
```

This goes on for 1000 lines. Is there a better way to define a variable based on many different user choices?

Comment: Have you considered storing the pricing in an XML file and looking it up with javascript?  Without using a server side language this will be time intensive to set up either way.

Comment: I have been trying another way using a 2d array which is much cleaner but still long, what server side language would you recommend is useful for this situation.

Comment: No matter which server side language you'd choose you'd need to get the data into a database.  I'm not sure how you currently have your data, if it is in Excel you can usually upload it to the database table.  Both PHP and ASP.NET are popular web-based projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put choices and prices in a property file. As property file works on key value pair, you just need to get the corresponding key from the user selection and get the price against it from Properties. This will also allow you to not hard code the price and color. You can create the drop down in html, and then populate it using the javascript. You can have the properties file reading logic in a java file, which can be referenced in your javascript.

Your property file may look like this:

```
galvalume=14.70
galvanized=13.35
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do I make a property file?

Comment: I think your assuming that I write Java, I have only worked with javascript.

Comment: There's no mention of server side code anywhere. If he doesn't have any server side code, this doesn't really work for him at all.

Comment: @ABBryan You cannot read properties file in the java script as it is the client side and file must be on the server side.

Comment: Yes so I want to do this using client side only.